# How to remove contacts from my Google Hangouts?

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

Does hiding a contact remove the person from Hangouts? I don't want these contacts to get my IP address. They seem like shady characters that I met on a fraudulent dating site.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. Hidden contacts are just hidden, not removed. To remove contacts do this:

- go to your Contacts: **https://contacts.google.com/**
- choose/find a name
- click on the 3-dots (on the right side of selection)
- select **Delete**

  [image]
- then go to Gmail: **https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/**
- click on Hangouts' icon

  [image]
- select name
- click on 3-dots
- select **Delete**

  [image]
- and confirm:

  [image]

Comment: Okay, but what if there isn't a contact in my google contacts that keeps popping up on my hangouts list?